# Render component dynamically based on bean attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Let's say I have a bean with a boolean variable called "Success". By default, this value is false.

i.e. If "Success" is true, I render a button. If "Success" is false, I render an outputText. The value of "Success" is determined by what a user inputs on an inputText field. If it's anything different from a 6 digit number, then "Success" is false.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You only need to make sure that typing in the input field causes an ajax submit to the server side, so that JSF can do its validation and rendering job. You can use `<f:ajax event="keyup">` for that. Then, you can just bind the input to a `Integer` property to convert/validate it as a valid number. Then, you can use `<f:validateLongRange>` to validate the number range.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:inputText binding="#{input}" value="#{bean.number}" maxlength="6">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="100000" maximum="999999" />
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="buttonOrText" />
</h:inputText>
<h:panelGroup id="buttonOrText">
    <h:commandButton value="button" rendered="#{facesContext.postback and input.valid}" />
    <h:outputText value="text" rendered="#{not (facesContext.postback and input.valid)}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that I didn't make use of any `success` boolean as that's unnecessary in this particular case. The information necessary for rendering is already available in EL scope and JSF component state. Here, [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) only returns `true` if a form submit is performed (ajax submits also count as postbacks). [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) only returns `true` if the postback didn't cause a conversion/validation error on the component. Action methods shouldn't be performing conversion/validation in any way.